# Add a new column based on two dataframes and conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How can I add a new column based on two dataframes and conditions?
For example, if df2['x'] is between df1['x']±2.5 and df2['y'] is between df1['y']±2.5,
give 1 otherwise 0.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'x': [40.1, 50.1, 60.1, 70.1, 80.1, 90.1, 0, 300.1 ], 'y': [100.1, 110.1, 120.1, 130.1, 140.1, 150.1, 160.1, 400.1], 'year': [2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2004]}   
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df              

     x        y     year
0   40.1    100.1   2000
1   50.1    110.1   2000
2   60.1    120.1   2001
3   70.1    130.1   2001
4   80.1    140.1   2003
5   90.1    150.1   2003
6   0.0     160.1   2003
7   300.1   400.1   2004
```

df2

```
data2 = {'x': [92.2, 30.1, 82.6, 51.1, 39.4, 10.1, 0, 299.1], 'y': [149.3, 100.1, 139.4, 111.1, 100.8, 180.1, 0, 402.5], 'year': [1950, 1951, 1952, 2000, 2000, 1954, 1955, 2004]}  
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df2

     x        y     year
0   92.2    149.3   1950
1   30.1    100.1   1951
2   82.6    139.4   1952
3   51.1    111.1   2000
4   39.4    100.8   2000
5   10.1    180.1   1954
6   0.0     0.0     1955
7   299.1   402.5   2004
```

Output: df

```
new_col = []
for i in df.index:
if ((df['x'].iloc[i] - 2.5) < df2['x'].iloc[i] < (df['x'].iloc[i] + 2.5) and 
    (df['y'].iloc[i] - 2.5) < df2['y'].iloc[i] < (df['y'].iloc[i] + 2.5) and 
    df['year'].iloc[i] == df2['year'].iloc[i]):
    out = 1
else:
    out = 0
       
if out == 1:
    new_coll.append(1)
else: 
    new_col.append(0)
df['Result'] = new_col
df
            
      x       y     year   Result
0   40.1    100.1   2000    0
1   50.1    110.1   2000    0
2   60.1    120.1   2001    0
3   70.1    130.1   2001    0
4   80.1    140.1   2003    0
5   90.1    150.1   2003    0
6   0.0     160.1   2003    0
7   300.1   400.1   2004    1
```

But the output is not correct in terms of what i want. It just compare row by row. I want to find: Is the first row in df inside df2 according to conditions? It means check all rows in df2 for each row in df. So the expected output should be as below:

Expected output: df

```
As you can see, 3 rows satisfy the conditions:
0 in df --> 4 in df2
1 in df --> 3 in df2
7 in df --> 7 in df2
    
So expected output:

     x        y     year   Result
0   40.1    100.1   2000    1
1   50.1    110.1   2000    1
2   60.1    120.1   2001    0
3   70.1    130.1   2001    0
4   80.1    140.1   2003    0
5   90.1    150.1   2003    0
6   0.0     160.1   2003    0
7   300.1   400.1   2004    1
```

Comment: `df2` is missing rows 3,4,5. Where do you expect the missing operands to come from? Do you expect `df2` to be recycled as it would be in R? Or else what operans?

Comment: Sorry, my question was not clear. Now, I updated it.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this code to work but please comment if it does not:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'x': [431228.6013, 431233.6013], 'y': [4522094.758, 4522094.758]}   
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
data2 = {'x': [431226.7421, 431280.9052], 'y': [4522093.800, 4522060.532]}  
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
new_col = []
for i in df.index:
    symbol = 'x'
    if 2.5 <= df[symbol].iloc[i] <= df2[symbol].iloc[i] or 2.5 >= df[symbol].iloc[i] >= df2[symbol].iloc[i]:
        x_out = 1
    else:
        x_out = 0
    symbol = 'y'
    if 2.5 <= df[symbol].iloc[i] <= df2[symbol].iloc[i] or 2.5 >= df[symbol].iloc[i] >= df2[symbol].iloc[i]:
        y_out = 1
    else:
        y_out = 0
    
    if x_out == y_out:
        new_col.append(1)
    else: 
        new_col.append(0)
df['Result'] = new_col
```

With this I got the answers that you expected above. Also, the df and df2 have to be the same length for this to work.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks a lot but unfortunately, it doesnt work. The error is " IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds". To better explain my data, I edited example dataframes.

Comment: that is probably because you have two dataframes or different lengths. You will need to have two datasets that have the same number of rows each for the code to work. You could try adding rows to df2 that contain values that you do not care about. You would have several results that you do not care about but the first three should be valid.

Comment: Ok, two dataframes have same lengths now. But I think I could not explain well what I want to ask. But according to your answer, I did somethings.  However it is not solve my problem. I updated my question and now, I think it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

**One-line solution:**

```
df['Result'] = (df - df2).abs().le(2.5).all(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Explanation: this relies on most operators and functions on DataFrames and Series being **vectorized**: not just arithmetic and logical expressions `.le()`, `.all()`/`.any()`, `.sum()`, `.apply()` all take an optional `(...axis=1)` argument.

First, slice the two columns of interest, vector-subtract them, compare the absolute value of the difference to 2.5 (instead of the three-way comparison `-2.5 < ... < 2.5`):

```
(df - df2)[['x','y']].abs().le(2.5)

       x      y
0  False  False
1  False  False
2  False  False
3  False  False
4  False  False
5  False  False
6   True  False
7   True   True
```

Now for each row `(..., axis=1)` we need to logical-and the columns into a boolean value, which we can then convert to int:

```
(df - df2)[['x','y']].abs().le(2.5).all(axis=1).astype(int)

0    0
1    0
2    0
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    0
7    1
```

Note:

- vectorization is faster, usually gives clearer, shorter code (avoid all that repetitive clunky `df['x'].iloc[i]`), and multiple operations/functions can be arbitrarily composed, as we do here.
- in your case, you want to take columns `['x', 'y', 'year']` all from `df`, then concatenate `df['Result']`. So essentially everything comes from `df` and we're just appending one new column. We don't even need to do `pd.concat([df, [...], axis=1)`, we might as well just directly assign `df['Result']`, it gets appended.

Comment: yes you re right. loop takes so long time because I have large dataframe. I apply different codes.  On the other hand, your answer is not correct. The result should be: 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,1